# How to get random element from a set in Swift?

Tags: swift, set

As of Swift 1.2, Apple introduces `Set` collection type.

Say, I have a set like:

```
var set = Set<Int>(arrayLiteral: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Now I want to get a random element out of it.  Question is how?  `Set` does not provide `subscript(Int)` like `Array` does.  Instead it has `subscript(SetIndex<T>)`.  But firstly, `SetIndex<T>` does not have accessible initializers (hence, I can not just create an index with the offset I need), and secondly even if I can get the index for a first element in a set (`var startIndex = set.startIndex`) then the only way I can get to the N-th index is through consecutive calls to `successor()`.

Therefore, I can see only 2 options at the moment, both ugly and expensive:

- Convert the set into array (`var array = [Int](set)`) and use its subscript (which perfectly accepts `Int`); or
- Get index of a first element in a set, traverse the chain of `successor()` methods to get to the N-th index, and then read corresponding element via set's subscript.

Do I miss some other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the best approach is `advance` which walks `successor` for you:

```
func randomElementIndex<T>(s: Set<T>) -> T {
    let n = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(s.count)))
    let i = advance(s.startIndex, n)
    return s[i]
}
```

(EDIT: Heh; noticed you actually updated the question to include this answer before I added it to my answer... well, still a good idea and I learned something too. :D)

You can also walk the set rather than the indices (this was my first thought, but then I remembered `advance`).

```
func randomElement<T>(s: Set<T>) -> T {
    let n = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(s.count)))
    for (i, e) in enumerate(s) {
        if i == n { return e }
    }
    fatalError("The above loop must succeed")
}
```

Comment: Yes.  The fun part though is that `advance()` in case of Set has complexity O(N).  So technically it's the same as traversing the chain of `successor()`, it simply looks much more concise and intention-clear.  I asked similar question at Apple developers forum, and it got an attention from the staff => maybe in some future release of Swift there would be better tools to do what I want.  For now I probably will stay with `advance()`.  The sets that I will use are not that big.

Comment: The advance method no longer compiles, as of Xcode 7 Beta 6

Comment: Justin Lewis all that has changed is that you must now call `advancedBy(_:)` on the index `extension Set { func randomElement() -> Element { let n = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))); let i = startIndex.advancedBy(n); return self[i];} }`

Comment: For swift 2, `advance` is no longer available. Change line 3 to `let i = s.startIndex.advancedBy(n)`

Comment: A little addition in swift 2: to enumerate a sequence you must call s.enumerate()

Answer (score 13):

Starting with Swift 4.2, you can use [`randomElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2996845-randomelement):

```
let random = set.randomElement()
```

Answer (score 5):

In swift 3

```
extension Set {
    public func randomObject() -> Element? {
        let n = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        let index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: n)
        return self.count > 0 ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension Set {
    func randomElement() -> Element? {
        return count == 0 ? nil : self[advance(self.startIndex, Int(arc4random()) % count)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per comments above re Swift updates, used a minor change for an extension to Set:

```
func randomElement() -> Element?
{
    let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
    let index = startIndex.advancedBy(randomInt)
    return count == 0 ? nil: self[index]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 'random' element from a `Set` then you use:

```
/// A member of the set, or `nil` if the set is empty.
var first: T? { get }
```

Get the 0th index or the 1,000,000th index makes no difference - they are all an arbitrary object.

But, **if you want repeated calls** to return a likely different element each time, then `first` might not fit the bill.

Comment: Of course, how could you possibly tell that .first. differs from 'walk over N-1, return the Nth'?  Does Swift makes a guarantee that the traverse order is constant over time?  Some languages don't (because the Set's hash depends on the memory address and in garbage collected systems the memory addresses change).

Comment: Because the hashing is deterministic. Given the same input, you'll get the same result every time you run. That's why it's like the xkcd algorithm. It's "random" but will repeat every time. The fact that this isn't promised, doesn't mean it won't actually happen in real programs. Try it. In a set of [10,20,30,40,50], I find that `first` is always 50.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence is not proof that the Set traversal is deterministic.

Comment: Not proof at all, and you can't rely on it (and you're right that it's important). But any program that relies on it *not* being deterministic (i.e. the user expects different answers during different runs) is going to be very disappointed. The Go language is interesting in this; it actually *promises* that iteration over maps (dictionaries) will occur in a random order, explicitly to prevent you relying on some order you *think* is guaranteed. But in Swift, using first is clever, but isn't going to match user expectations for any likely use case.

Comment: @GoZoner - And anecdotal evidence is not proof that the element of a set returned by .first is truly random. An "arbitrary" object *does not equal* a random object.